# How do I use a legacy javascript library as a scoped dependency of an Angular service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, legacy-code

Specifically, I am working with an ~800 line SCORM API wrapper library that facilitates communication with an LMS.  The author did not write it in Angular. A legacy, vanilla js file(index.js) has been wrapped over top of it I'm including a snippet of both to give an idea of the structure being used here.

```
SCORM = {                                           //Define the SCORM object
    version:    null,                               //Store SCORM version.
    handleCompletionStatus: true,                   //Whether or not the wrapper should automatically handle the initial completion status
    handleExitMode: true,                           //Whether or not the wrapper should automatically handle the exit mode
    API:        { handle: null,
                  isFound: false }                  //Create API child object


};
SCORM.API.get = function(){ //implementation};
SCORM.API.set = function(){ //implementation};
```

On top of this is a legacy javascript file that executes in global scope.

index.js

```
var scorm = SCORM;
var interval;
var channel;
function init(){
  scorm.version 
}
function get(params){
    var values;
    values = getFromLMS(params); 
    return values;
}
function set(param, value){
    return scorm.set(param, value);
    return callSucceeded;
}
```

I am writing a greenfield app in Angular, but I would like to leverage some existing external libraries in my architecture.  I would really like to expose index.js' functionality as an Angular service without having to completely rewrite it.

If I were to give you the two javascript files mentioned above and a new services.js file that had the following structure

```
'use strict';

var learnerServices = angular.module('learnerServices', []);

learnerServices.factory('learner-service' [
    function(){

        });
    }
]);
```

how would you inject the "get" and "set" functions from index.js into the $scope of the learner-service?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I interpreted your question correctly...

```
'use strict';
 var learnerServices = angular.module('learnerServices', []);

 learnerServices.factory('scormService' [
   function() {

    var scorm = SCORM;
    var interval;
    var channel;
    function init(){
      scorm.version 
    }
    function get(params){
      var values;
      values = getFromLMS(params); 
      return values;
    }
    function set(param, value){
      return scorm.set(param, value);
      return callSucceeded;
    }

   return  {
     scorm: scorm,
     interval: interval,
     channel: channel,
     init: init,
     get: get,
     set: set
   }
  });
]);

learnerServices.factory('learnerService' ['scormService'
  function(scormService){
    scormService.get('some param');
  });

]);
```

Comment: Perhaps that is the best way to go, and I'm going to work that into a test shortly. But, what I was specifically looking for was a way to reference the existing code that is inside index.js from within my angular learnerService (i.e. No copy/pasting,) To state it another way, I want to create an angular service that serves as an adapter to the legacy code by exposing its API to angular scoped contexts without implementing its internals.

Comment: maybe I'm just over thinking it and should just copy the legacy internals into my factory, as you have done in your reply.

Comment: Yes, you could use the factory as a wrapper. But you would need to return an object exposing variables/functions which you wish to access from outside.

Comment: I guess a more basic question is, where does my script tag that references index.js and the one that references SCORM_wrapper.js go such that learnerServices has visibility into them?

Comment: @K.AlanBates, put the scripts in index.html at the end of the body tag (right before closing off body), but make sure angular.js is defined first so it loads first. Might be worth checking out some basic angular app examples to see how they structure their projects. A good example is TodoMVC - http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/angularjs/ ...there is a link to source on the top left corner of the page. If you have coded SCORM_wrapper.js and learnerServices.js using the angular framework, then angular will pick these up. You can put some console.log statements in your code to confirm load

Comment: thanks for the comment but I wasn't asking about how to add a script tag to a body and I wasn't trying to add it to index.html (notice, I asked for a way to make it a *scoped* dependency. Adding it to body of index would just pollute global space) I was asking if there was any way to inject a legacy library into a controller without modularizing it, which was a pretty stupid question on my part because the easiest way to accomplish what I was trying to do was to cut the legacy code apart and paste it into a new service.

Comment: @K.AlanBates, are you using gulp or grunt in your build process? You could create a comment placeholder in your angular service, then in your gulp (i find this more flexible than grunt) task load in the contents of your legacy script, and use a plugin such as gulp-replace to inject the legacy script into the angular service in place of the comment placeholder.